# Customizing django admin site - in row buttons

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    some_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and

```
class Bar(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Then I register my models in django AdminSite using FooAdmin class:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'year', 'some_value']
```

It works fine, but for some reason I need to add two buttons for each Foo row in my admin site. Let's say I'd call them 'Related_button' and 'Action_button'

I need those buttons to be in each row and to behave as follows:
-when user clicks on 'Related_button', he is redirected to django admin site where all Bars related with particullar Foo object are listed
-when user clicks on 'Action_button', a field some_value in object of class Foo is set to a custom value, let's say 15. But before that, confirm popup (Are you sure? y/n) should appear.

How to do that? I figured out that I could do something like:

```
def button(self, obj):
    return '''<input type="button" value="button" />'''
button.short_description = 'Action'
button.allow_tags = True
list_display = ['name', 'year', 'some_value', 'action']
```

in my FooAdmin which causes a button to appear in each row. But how can I set an action for that button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list page is a form.

```
<form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post">
```

Adding buttons to it will submit the form. To do something with the formdata you have to create a custom admin form. It will be dirty because it's a fromset containing all displayed rows, and not just your single row. I guess it can be done, but there are better ways:

Most of the time [Admin Actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) will do just fine. Admin actions look like this:

[image: Admin actions]

```
def rename_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(name='Ni')
make_published.short_description = "Rename selected objects to 'Ni'"

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [rename_action, ...]
```

But if you want more flexibility than an Admin Action, feel free to write custom views for the admin. The admin is powered by Django itself, and you can write custom views that hook into the authentication system, check permissions and do whatever else they need to do. It goes like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

    def my_action_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="/admin/app/foo/my_custom_action/%d/" class="link">Action name</a>' %obj.id
    my_action_link.short_description = 'My action'
    my_action_link.allow_tags = True
```

Now my action is a link that points to some [custom url and custom admin view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls). Create a custom admin view:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    list_display = ['name', 'my_action_link', ...]

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(FooAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_custom_action/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    @permission_required('foo.can_change')
    def my_view(self, request):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=pk)
        obj.do_something()
        # Redirect back to the change list. Or something else?
        # You could add some modelform to this view. :)
```

I didn't test this code. But I hope you get the idea. Happy hacking!

[EDITED]: Linked reference Django 1.6 URLs not working anymore. Added Django 1.11 URLs

Comment: Thank you, that loooks great! But I'm worried about one thing - I have also modified queryset mehtod in my FooAdmin as follows : return Foo.objects.filter(created_by=request.user). Is my_view looking for Foo object in my filtered set or is it retrieving it directly from database? I don't want to let my user see things he's not allowed to.

Comment: I guess your user could be fiddling with the url. But you could do: `obj = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=pk, created_by=request.user)` if a obj isn't created by that user it'll raise a 404.

Comment: Or course there are other ways. Check and return a useful message: `if request.user != obj.created_by: return "This incident will be reported."`

Comment: To answer your comment question: This is a regular view and will query the db. It has nothing to do with the admin qs method.

Comment: Thanks. And one last question : is it possible to change django admin actions so that they work as a buttons instead of that menu you showed above?

Comment: Not in a 'Django way' that I know of. But Django comes with jQuery so you might use that. You can include your own sripts in the admin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions. Note that Django’s jQuery is namespaced as django.jQuery. Tip: Every change list row has a checkbox with the id of the obj as it's value.

Comment: Also see this article on adding button(s) to each row of the change list, also allowing for intermediate forms for user inputs:  https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41

Answer (score -1):

Add custom js to admin class:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'year', 'some_value']

    class Media:
        js = ("/media/javascript/yourjs.js",)
```

Comment: Could you write something more? Unfortunately, I don't know java script. And which one of my problems should it solve?